# Adding callback to javascript while loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, jquery-callback

I am trying to replicate a type-writer effect on a resume page of mine, and have if working except for one part:

```
while (i < tags.length) {
    type(tags[i], content[i], 0, 50);
    i++;
}
```

This is the function that writes out the lines, and it works correctly, except for the fact that it writes all of the lines at once. I would like for it to write a single line, then move on to the next, and so on and so forth. I know the solution lies in adding a callback function in but I can't seem to get it to work right. Any help/advice would be appreciated. Thanks!

Also, here is the full [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h85mz20u/52/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A callback and a recursive function seems like the way to go

```
var type = function (target, message, index, interval, callback) {    
    if (index < message.length) { 
        $(target).append(message[index++]); 
        setTimeout(function () { 
            type(target, message, index, interval, callback); 
        }, interval); 
    } else {
        callback();
    }
}

var i = 0;

(function recursive() {
    if (i < tags.length) {
        type(tags[i], content[i], 0, 50, recursive);
        i++;
    }
})();
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/h85mz20u/54/)

Comment: That is pretty awesome, does exactly what I want. Thanks for the quick response. Where is a good spot to views some docs on the setTimeout idea?

Comment: This is pretty neat. But I don't like the outcome, personally. One has to wait and see all the content load.

Comment: [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) generally has good documentation on JavaScript.

Comment: @yellen - that's what the OP asked for, and in some cases it can be neat, as long as one knows that the visitor will sit around and wait for it I suppose.

Comment: @adeneo - Sorry, was not targeted to your solution. :P

Comment: @yellen Yeah the visitor will have to wait, but only for a couple seconds. I think the effect is worth it :)